# tf2_ros:.Buffer definition causes crash of nodelet, undefined symbol undefined symbol: _ZTVN7tf2_ros6BufferE

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, nodelet, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm building a nodelet with ROS Melodic. The nodelet publishes a pointcloud based on bumper messages, similar to http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_bumper2pc.
I try to adopt this behaviour for a given (own build) robot. In general, my code is working, when not using any tf2 package. It compiles fine and runs good so far.

Because my robot model has separate frames for left and right bumper, I wanted to use tf2 to set the points at the right place in respect to base_frame. As these are static frames, I wanted to use get x,y offset of each bumper frame from tf tree.

For some reason, as soon as I place this line in my class, it fails to run but compiles with no error.

```
tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer; <-- this causes the error
```

This line must just be part of header file and the nodelet crashes. Even if I remove any tf2 related code, it fails as soon as this definition is part of the header.

I can't figure out why this happens. It would be great, if someone can help me to figure things out.

This error occurs, but doesn't if I comment it out:

```
    started roslaunch server http://ubuntu-jetson:35617/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.12

NODES
  /
    Bumper2PCNodelet (nodelet/nodelet)
    base_controller (ros_hovermower_base_controller/ros_hovermower_base_controller)
    standalone_nodelet (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [10534]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 9cc5535a-9e2c-11ec-82cd-520628f4d385
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [10547]
started core service [/rosout]
process[base_controller-2]: started with pid [10550]
process[standalone_nodelet-3]: started with pid [10560]
process[Bumper2PCNodelet-4]: started with pid [10568]
[ INFO] [1646667501.947591664]: Loading nodelet /Bumper2PCNodelet of type ros_hovermower_base_controller/Bumper2PcNodelet to manager standalone_nodelet with the following remappings:
[ INFO] [1646667501.970422695]: waitForService: Service [/standalone_nodelet/load_nodelet] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1646667501.973934612]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1646667501.987027620]: Reconfigure Request: timeout_smag: 200 timeout: 10 
[ INFO] [1646667501.996778507]: waitForService: Service [/standalone_nodelet/load_nodelet] is now available.
[ INFO] [1646667502.016520080]: Initialized dynamic reconfigure
[ INFO] [1646667502.016709772]: Timeout smag  200
[ INFO] [1646667502.016864933]: Timeout  10
[ERROR] [1646667502.076439711]: Failed to load nodelet [/Bumper2PCNodelet] of type [ros_hovermower_base_controller/Bumper2PcNodelet] even after refreshing the cache: Failed to load library /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libros_hovermower_base_controller_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libros_hovermower_base_controller_nodelet.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN7tf2_ros6BufferE)
[ERROR] [1646667502.076723833]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Failed to load library /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libros_hovermower_base_controller_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libros_hovermower_base_controller_nodelet.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN7tf2_ros6BufferE)
[FATAL] [1646667502.077329891]: Failed to load nodelet '/Bumper2PCNodelet` of type `ros_hovermower_base_controller/Bumper2PcNodelet` to manager `standalone_nodelet'
[Bumper2PCNodelet-4] process has died [pid 10568, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load ros_hovermower_base_controller/Bumper2PcNodelet standalone_nodelet __name:=Bumper2PCNodelet __log:=/home/ros/.ros/log/9cc5535a-9e2c-11ec-82cd-520628f4d385/Bumper2PCNodelet-4.log].
log file: /home/ros/.ros/log/9cc5535a-9e2c-11ec-82cd-520628f4d385/Bumper2PCNodelet-4*.log
```

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef _HOVERMOWER_BUMPER2PC_H
#define _HOVERMOWER_BUMPER2PC_H

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>

#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <ros_hovermower_base_controller/HoverMowerBaseControllerConfig.h>
#include "rosmower_msgs/Bumper.h"
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>

namespace ros_hovermower_base_controller
{

    class Bumper2PcNodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet
    {
    public:
        Bumper2PcNodelet()
            : P_INF_X(+100 * sin(0.34906585)),
              P_INF_Y(+100 * cos(0.34906585)),
              N_INF_Y(-100 * cos(0.34906585)),
              ZERO(0), prev_bumper_left_(false), prev_bumper_right_(false) {}
        ~Bumper2PcNodelet() {}

        void onInit();
        void dyn_callback(ros_hovermower_base_controller::HoverMowerBaseControllerConfig &config, uint32_t level);

    private:
        const float P_INF_X; // somewhere out of reach from the robot (positive x)
        const float P_INF_Y; // somewhere out of reach from the robot (positive y)
        const float N_INF_Y; // somewhere out of reach from the robot (negative y)
        const float ZERO;

        bool prev_bumper_left_;
        bool prev_bumper_right_;

        // additional bumper attributes
        std::string bumper_left_frame_;
        std::string bumper_right_frame_;
        std::string base_frame_;

        float pc_radius_;
        float pc_height_;
        float pc_angle_;
        float p_side_x_;
        float p_side_y_;
        float n_side_y_;
        float distance_x_;
        float distance_y_;

        // tf transformation between base_frame and bumper frames
        float bumper_frame_left_x = 0.0;
        float bumper_frame_left_y = 0.0;
        float bumper_frame_right_x = 0.0;
        float bumper_frame_right_y = 0.0;
           tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;   //<------------ this causes the error

        ros::Publisher bumper_pc_pub_;
        ros::Subscriber base_controller_bumper_sub_;

        sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 bumper_pc_;

        void bc_bumperCB(const rosmower_msgs::Bumper::ConstPtr &msg);
        void get_tf_bumper();

        // dynamic reconfigure
        typedef dynamic_reconfigure::Server<ros_hovermower_base_controller::HoverMowerBaseControllerConfig> DynamicReconfigServer;
        boost::shared_ptr<DynamicReconfigServer> param_reconfig_server_;
        DynamicReconfigServer::CallbackType param_reconfig_callback_;
    };

} // namespace ros_hovermower_base_controller

#endif
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397198/tf2_ros:.buffer-definition-causes-crash-of-nodelet,-undefined-symbol-undefined-symbol:-_ztvn7tf2_ros6buffere/) by [PaddyCube](https://answers.ros.org/users/40932/paddycube/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2022-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-03-07**:
Quick comment: this is not a crash. It's the nodelet manager's `pluginlib` instance telling you it cannot resolve all the symbols in your shared library (as that's what nodelets are in the end) as it attempts to load it.

You need to check you're linking your library to all the other libraries you're using. In this specific case: the TF2 libraries.

And I'm saying "this is not a crash" as none of your code has been executed when the `ERROR` is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you @gvdhoorn for this hint.

I missed to add them as build and exec_depend in package.xml as well as find_packages in CMakeLists.txt.
After fixing this in both files, it starts to work.

I'm wondering why I was able to build without any errors before, but now it works.

---

Originally posted by [PaddyCube](https://answers.ros.org/users/40932/paddycube/) with karma: 76 on 2022-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-03-08**:\

> I'm wondering why I was able to build without any errors before

by default, the linker, when linking a shared library, will assume any symbols it cannot resolve at build-time will be resolved at runtime.

In your case, there were no errors as the linker basically assumed the nodelet manager would "know" where to find the symbols it couldn't find (not really the nodelet manager of course, as the linker doesn't know anything about that, but whatever entity was going to consume the shared library).